# place 6 scrollable tables in the right half of the screen one beneath the other

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I need to place 6 user-defined asp.net tables (each table is in a div) such that they occupy the right half of the screen and these tables are placed one beneath the other. Additionally each table is scrollable because each table has a minimum of 20 entries.

I use the following div classes but only the first two tables are placed one beneath the other. the other 4 are all over the place.

```
.Occupy_Right_Half {
 float:right;
 overflow:hidden;
}

#scroll {
overflow-y: auto;
 height:400px;
 width:42%;   
border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
}
```

I hardly work with css, so please excuse me for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```css
.tables {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.tables div {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.tables div:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="tables">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

If six tables should squeeze into the height, and (as you said) have vertical scroll bar, take a look on this solution:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tables {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}

.tables div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 16.666%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.tables div:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="tables">
  <div>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
    <p>Entry</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks a lot for your solution. works great but there is one issue.

When any of these tables is empty, two scroll bars appear. I am basically getting data from different database tables and displaying in all of these tables.

so for six tables, I have 12 scrollbars now. 2 each on the right side. Am I missing something ?

Comment: try to use "overflow: hidden;" instead of "overflow-y: auto;" then?

Comment: Do you have a link, or can you share some code, or use jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue please?

Comment: I figured it out! somehow, it was thinking that there is a div inside another div. Hence the two scrollbars per table. I changed the .tables div to .tablesdiv (another class) and used it for all the table divs. It worked

Comment: still testing it thought!

Comment: HI Mike, I have another qustion I would like to add some space between every table. any suggestions ?

Comment: Hi @neo if we simply add margin it will be calculated from the width, so the solution is to make a wrapper and inside this wrapper we set inner div padding, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/8ako5u1t/ but I would recommend you to read about flex-box and implement this in your project.